# How Can i Click on The Same Button For 99 Times or Till The Code Ends?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Need a Solution, Please Help.

Am Having Same Skip Button Type,name id Property For All Products. Only The Xpath Changes. Please Guide Me How Can i Shortly Click on 99 Same Skip Buttons and One Cancel Popup Button.

Here My Image For Skip Button

[image: Skip Button Image]

Here My Image, After Clicking on SKip, I Will Get a Pop Up Like This. I That I Need To Click on Cancel

[image: Cancel Image]

Down i Will Be Attaching The Code For SKIP and Cancel.

From The Html Code For Skip Button, I Took an Xpath its Working Only,

My Xpath is

```
//input[@id='CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_0'])-Product1
 //input[@id='CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_1'])-Product2
  //input[@id='CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_2'])-Product3

Like this 99 Products I Have To Write Xpath. It's Going Too Lengthy
```

Html Code For Skip Button is

```
 <input type="submit" name="CustomPaging_GridView$ctl02$gv_edit1" value="SKIP" onclick="product_skip(37639 );" id="CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_0" class="button2">
```

HTML Code For Cancel Button,

```
<div class="modal-footer">
                <span id="prcid" style="display:none;">processing...</span>
                <button type="button" id="skipok" onclick="skipoverall(this)" class="btn btn-primary" data-id="37639">Ok</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
```

*PS: Each Time When i Click on The Skip button i Need To Click on The Cancel Button Simultaneously. Like That I Need To Click On Skip Button and Cancel Button For 99 Products*

Comment: To match your input, you can use partial ID matching. //*[contains(@id, 'CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_')] or //*[starts-with(@id, 'CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_')]

Comment: Okay @JonathanHamel First i Thought of That Only, But Suddenly i Had a Thought Why Can't We Use For Loop Function and Click on Button For 99 Times Simultaneously?

Comment: @koushick, you can also check for the condition till the button is displayed, may be using while loop or something similar. Hence, not limiting to 99 or any number.

Comment: @eduPeeth i Can't Get it Man! Please Can You Elobrate? Am Stuck!!

Comment: Few things, what happens when you click Skip button does it disappear after clicking cancel? Are all the skip button available at the same time on the page?

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani , As You Asked When i Click on The Skip Button it Will Give an Pop up "Do You Want To Skip This Product , Click On Okay or Cancel" Like That in One Page Their are 99 Skip Button and i Will Get 99 Popups, in That Popup i need To Click on Cancel Button Each Time When i Click on Skip Button . i Hope You  Get it What Am Try Say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try -

```
public void clickSkipAndCancel(){
            List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_')]"));
            for (Iterator<WebElement> iterator = elements.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                WebElement webElement = (WebElement) iterator.next();
                new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .until(new Predicate<WebDriver>() 
                       {
                         @Override
                         public boolean apply(@Nullable WebDriver driver) {
                         webElement.click();
                         return true;
                       }
});

                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']")).click();
            }                
        }
```

You will have to import -

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
```

Let me know if it works for you or otherwise.

Comment: Down i Have Posted The Issue, i Tried in The Above Method it is Working. But it is Working Working Only Upto a  Point of Time.

Comment: @koushick, I have edited some code above. Would you mind trying it? Lemme know if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks For Your Coorporation, Same it is Clicking Upto a Point of Time and Now Throwing Different Unknown Error. :(

Comment: Please try once more now. Also, can you put a counter and see how many times it clicks. And if you can put a debugger and see where it fails.

Comment: @koushick, glad if it was of any help to you. Please upvote.

Comment: Sure Man! Thanks For Help. Be in Touch !

Comment: Surely :). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So given the information I would try below kind of code. Since you have not mentioned language I would give logic in python

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'CustomPaging_GridView_gv_edit1_')]")

for elem in elems:
    elem.click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']").click()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tarun Lalwani , Can You Suggest in Java?

Comment: Its just 4 lines try to convert in Java yourself, you will understand this better